# After Updating Xamarin Forms 4.8 to 5 Xamarin UWP Project Crashed with unhandled Exception in App Designer Page

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel, uwp-xaml

I got this exception :**{"Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'."}**

and Message is :

**System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.at System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.CarouselViewRenderer.InitialSetup(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)**

Anyone had faced this issue??

Comment: Did you tried to clean your solution and rebuild?

Comment: Yes i did but looks like there is some other issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to  [Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.1874 (5.0.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0) Release Notes.  And remove type list contains [`CarouselViewRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0#removed-type-xamarinformsplatformtizennativeembeddingcontrols), so it will not available for version 5.0. please check if you have used  `CarouselView`, and remove it.